# why clear timeout is not working ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am doing like a loop with 5 secs to call a function.
Here is my code  like

```
var timeouts = [];
   res.forEach(function (entry) {
     timeouts[entry] = [];
   });

   for (var entry in new_image_list) {
    for(var newentry in new_image_list[entry])
    {           {
          timeouts[entry][newentry] =setTimeout('load_image_file(' + entry + ',' + newentry          + ')', timer * 5000);
    timer++;
}
}
```

if cancel loop button was clicked

function content was like

```
for (var entry in timeouts) {
    for(var newentry in timeouts[entry])
    {
        clearTimeout(timeouts[entry][newentry]);
    }
}
```

am trying to clear timeouts with clearTimeout function. but why it is not working?

Comment: Make sure whether it is hitting the `clearTimeout(timeouts[entry][newentry]);`..  If possible create a fiddle to reproduce the bug

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

Change `clearTimeout(timeouts[entry][newentry])` to `clearTimeout(newentry)`

Comment: It won't work because `timeouts` is an object and its structure is `timeouts = {entry: {newentry: setTimeout('load_image_file(' + entry + ',' + newentry          + ')', timer * 5000)}}`..  Therefore your answer will never work.

Comment: Then I think, first you have to check whether the `clearTimeout(timeouts[entry][newentry])` is getting fired.

Comment: [Thats it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23005139/why-clear-timeout-is-not-working/23005579?noredirect=1#comment35137395_23005139)  but I can't check it ;) OP needs to do it